# Android get latest AOSP commits into my project

Tags: android, dependency-management

My Android application faced some freezing issues in some rare scenarios. After some research I found that this issue was caused by an Android bug which already was reported at `issuetracker.google.com`. Recently I got notified that the issue was fixed.

Now my question is, how do I make sure that this commit to AOSP that should presumably fix the freezes is already included in my project? It might have something to do with the build.gradle file, which looks like this:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.1.0'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha03'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta4'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    ...
}
```

For every implementation, a version number exists. So do I have to wait until Google releases the latest version of the package in which the fix is included and then use this latest version? Or will I get the latest fix just by resyncing the project?

I apologize if this is a stupid question, but I did not quite understand yet how the sync between the AOSP repository and my Android project works. Thanks in advance for any help.

Link to the Bug on [Issuetracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/131851825). It is required to log in with a Google Account to view the Issuetracker.

Comment: Link the bug that was fixed. You have to work out which project (inside of AOSP) it was a part of, and update the version number for that dependency (if you can).

Comment: That issue tracker isn't even AOSP, which would be `componentid:190923`, but AndroidX.

Comment: @MartinZeitler Could you further explain what you mean? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say '**androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0-alpha03**'.

From the [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/131851825) we learn the link to the [Patch](https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/support/+/971248/) that fixed the bug. In the patch page, we see the fix is in the 'appcompat' folder/library (the list of modified files at the bottom). Also, in the top-left, we see the repository and the branch where the patch was merged (repo platform/frameworks/support, branch androidx-master-dev). It is important that the patch is marked as MERGED. Only merged patches are integrated into released libraries.

Clicking on [the branch link](https://android-review.googlesource.com/q/project:platform%252Fframeworks%252Fsupport+branch:androidx-master-dev+status:merged) sends us to the repo/branch from which all androidx.* libs are built (See these [instructions how to build androidx.*](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support) libs yourself and use them locally). Here we have to search for the patch that fixed that bug but the androidx repository receives a lot of patches and the list is pretty long. Fortunately, that search/filter box from top-right accepts a directory key. By adding 'directory:appcompat' in the search box we see only the patches from [appcompat lib](https://android-review.googlesource.com/q/directory:appcompat+project:platform/frameworks/support+branch:androidx-master-dev+status:merged). It is easy to spot the '**Fix stopped Activities not resuming on < API 24**' patch and right above it another patch '**Bump AppCompat version to 1.2.0-alpha03**' that sets the version for the fixed appcompat lib.

Comment: Thanks for this, as I think it gives me a better understanding on what is going on in all that IssueTracker stuff. What wonders me is that if I bump the gradle imnplementation ton `androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0-alpha03`, it won't build, as it says 'Failed to resolve...'- Maybe Martin Zeitler can provide further help.
Strangely, right now I also wasn't able to reproduce the issue, seems that it might have been fixed somehow. Strange.